# xmldom breaking on writing value of attribute

Tags: windows-installer, wildfly-10, setattribute, xmldom, installscript

I am trying to replace existing value of some attribute in `.xml` file. The line that is to be written is `${VAULT::ab::a-b::1}`
When I try to write it using `xmldom` or existing string replacement functions in InstallScript, I see that the file gets updated with above string but curly bracket at the end (`}`) goes to another line.
This is happening at 2 instances in XML file. I have no idea why this happens. I think curly braces don't need an escape though.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wacky about that string value. Perhaps you could share sample excerpts of your code in case the cause is specific to how you're doing it?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Using string Replacement methods in installscript i am using code : nResult=FileInsertLine (szFileName, szReturnLine, nLineNo, REPLACE);  Using XMLDOM i am using set oXMLConnAttriNode=oXMLNodeList.item(nIndex).selectSingleNode("security/password");         oXMLConnAttriNode.text="${"+szDB_Password+"}"; where szDB_Password is property that is being read from an existing file. I see value correctly deduced for property in the msi logs. Both these tend to put } to next line of ::1 in variable above in question

Comment: And after updation string in .xml shows as: <keystore path="a.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="${VAULT::ab::a-b::1
}" alias="xyz"/>.  Notice there is space after 1 and } , and in XML it is into 2 different lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional information in your comments, I believe your variable `szDB_Password` contains a newline or a carriage return and linefeed.

You could figure out how those charcters are getting into your variable and address that, or you could remove them later. To remove them, either resize the string; use [StrSub](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/Subsystems/installshield21langref/helplibrary/LangrefStrSub.htm) to exclude the last character or two; or use [StrReplace](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/Subsystems/installshield21langref/helplibrary/StrReplace.htm) twice to replace `"\r"` and `"\n"` each with `""`.

Comment: Yea, I could see a new line at the end of .txt file where i was reading up and storing up property from. May be wildfly commands were writing o/p the way including new line at end. Thanks for pointing it out and your valuable inputs, Michael.